# Default pip install to --user on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package-managers

I am using `pip` as my package manager for Python on my Windows 11 machine. I always install all my packages to `--user`. So, having to add `--user` argument every time I install a package is kind of annoying since it's my desired default installation path already!

```
> pip install package1 package2 package3 --user
```

On Ubuntu, if `sudo pip` is not used (which is recommended not to use it), pip install defaults to user

```sh
$ pip install package1 package2 package3
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
...
```

Is there any way to force pip to install packages to user by default as if `--user` argument is added without explicitly appending it at the end?

> I always add `--user --upgrade --verbose` to any `pip install` command

Comment: Try to look for something like "commans alias on Windows"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at the pip documentation [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration).

For the following to work you might have to go to File Explorer and at the top go to View and make sure you have selected hidden items from the options.

You will need to specify the default install location within a pip.ini file. Which, is usually located at `%APPDATA%\local\pip\pip.ini(on Windows)`.

The `%APPDATA%` is located in `C:\Users\username` then go to AppData on Windows.

You may have to create the `pip.ini` file when you find your pip directory. Within your pip.ini you will then need to put something like:

```
[global]
target=C:\Users\user
```

user being your username for your Windows machine.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer as it redirect me to look in depth in documentation. However, the solution was to create a`pip.ini` in `C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini` adding `[global]user = yes`. Not all options are listed [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#location) but with some trial and error I finally managed to solve it.

Comment: @Tes3awy I will edit my answer, for the answer to work on all computers. Looks like different computers have different ways of fixing things because after finding out your results the above answer only works for some people.